Constructing non-split $\mathbf{G}_m$-extensions of elliptic curves
I would like to find examples of abelian surfaces $A$ over a DVR $R$ with residue field $k$, so that the special fibre of $A$ is a non-split $\mathbf{G}_{m/k}$-extension of an elliptic curve over $k$.
For example, I could take a product of elliptic curves $E_1 \times E_2$ over $\mathbf{Z}_p$, with $E_1$ having multiplicative reduction and $E_2$ having good reduction. This leads to the split extension $\mathbf{G}_{m/\mathbf{F}_p} \times (E_2)_{(p)}$, but I would really like to see examples where the extension is non-split.
I was thinking of doing this using the LMFDB entries on genus two curves over $\mathbf{Q}$, and filtering for those curves having simple Jacobians, but I'm unsure how to choose a prime with the special fibre behaviour that I'm looking for.
I know that $\textrm{Ext}^1_{\mathbf{F}_p}(E, \mathbf{G}_m) \cong E(\mathbf{F}_p)$ for an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$, but I want to start with, say, an abelian surface in char zero, obtaining the $\mathbf{G}_m$-extension by reduction mod $p$.
Apologies for any errors.

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be elliptic curves over $\mathbb Z_p$, with $E_1$ having multipliicative reduction and $E_2$ having good reduction. Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be torsion points of $E_1$ and $E_2$ of order $n>1$, such that $P_1$ extends to a section over $\mathbb Z_p$ that reduces mod $p$ to a point in the identity component $\mathbb G_m$.
Then $(E_1 \times E_2)/ \langle (P_1,P_2)\rangle$ has the desired property. Its reduction mod $p$ is $(\mathbf G_{m/\mathbf F_p} \times (E_2)_{(p)})/ \langle (P_1,P_2)\rangle$, which is a $\mathbf G_{m/\mathbf F_p}$-bundle on $(E_2)_{(p)})/\langle P_2\rangle$. A section of this bundle would pull back to a section of $\mathbf G_{m/\mathbf F_p} \times (E_2)_{(p)}$, viewed as a trivial $\mathbf G_{m/\mathbf F_p} $-bundle on $(E_2)_{(p)}$, which is $(P_1,P_2)$-invariant, which is impossible: The only sections are constant sections which are invariant under $P_2$ but not $P_1$.

Nice. Might one be able to deform this in the moduli space to get an example of an abelian surface that is not isogenous to a product of elliptic curves. Or possibly find a genus 2 curve whose Jacobian has the desired property. Also, it took me a minute to understand why you specified that $P_1$ reduces to a torsion point of $\mathbb G_m$, since it obviously reduces to a torsion point. So in that sentence, the words "torsion point" aren't actually necessary, wha's important is that $P_1$ reduces to the identity component of the special fiber.

@JoeSilverman If you find any abelian surface whose special fiber is a product of an elliptic curve and $\mathbb G_m$, a similar quotient construction will work (either over the base ring or an unramiifed extension) to produce an example with non-split special fiber. So this construction works pretty generically in the moduli space.

To get a genus $2$ curve, you need a principal polarization. One could start with something with a non-principal polarization and quotient out to make it principal, or else quotient by a non-cyclic subgroup. The generators can't both lie in the identity component of the multiplicative fiber but I think you can keep track of what happens to the different components and get a similar conclusion.
